# Replace specific named group with re.sub in python

Tags: python, regex, string-substitution

I create a regular expression to find urls like `/places/:state/:city/whatever`

```
p = re.compile('^/places/(?P<state>[^/]+)/(?P<city>[^/]+).*$')
```

This works just fine:

```
import re

p = re.compile('^/places/(?P<state>[^/]+)/(?P<city>[^/]+).*$')
path = '/places/NY/NY/other/stuff'
match = p.match(path)
print match.groupdict()
```

Prints `{'city': 'NY', 'state': 'NY'}`.

How can I process a logfile to replace `/places/NY/NY/other/stuff` with the string `"/places/:state/:city/other/stuff"`?  I'd like to get a sense of how many urls are of the "cities-type" without caring that the places are (`NY`, `NY`) specifically.

The simple approach can fail:

```
import re

p = re.compile('^/places/(?P<state>[^/]+)/(?P<city>[^/]+).*$')
path = '/places/NY/NY/other/stuff'
match = p.match(path)
if match:
  groupdict = match.groupdict()
  for k, v in sorted(groupdict.items()):
    path = path.replace(v, ':' + k, 1)
print path
```

Will print `/places/:city/:state/other/stuff`, which is backwards!

Feels like there should be some way to use `re.sub` but I can't see it.

Comment: You've sorted the dict, so `city` comes before `state` during the replacement

Comment: @MosesKoledoye is the value returned by `groupdict()` guaranteed to be sorted in the same order as the matches (or any particular order at all)?  It seems to be just a built-in `<type 'dict'>`.

Comment: Yes, it's more or less the builtin `dict`. The ordering of the items in the dict will not reflect the order of the matches.

Comment: Using re.findall you can get the captures in the right order and in re.sub you can replace the text with back references to the captured parts.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew while that is true, unfortunately it doesn't give me the group name along with the matches, so I'd have to store that separately from the regex itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out a better way to do this.  There is a property `groupindex` on a compiled regular expression which prints the groups *and their orders* in the pattern string:

```
>>> p = re.compile('^/places/(?P<state>[^/]+)/(?P<city>[^/]+).*$')
>>> p.groupindex
{'city': 2, 'state': 1}
```

Which can easily be iterated in the correct order:

```
>>> sorted(p.groupindex.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
[('state', 1), ('city', 2)]
```

Using this, I should be able to guarantee that I replace matches in their correct left-to-right order:

```
p = re.compile('^/places/(?P<state>[^/]+)/(?P<city>[^/]+).*$')
path = '/places/NY/NY/other/stuff'
match = p.match(path)
if match:
    groupdict = match.groupdict()
    for k, _ in sorted(p.groupindex.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]):
        path = path.replace(groupdict[k], ':' + k, 1)
print path
```

This loops over the groups in the correct order, which ensures that the replacement also occurs in the correct order, reliably resulting in the correct string:

```
/places/:state/:city/other/stuff
```